# Classify or match similar patients together with machine learning techniques based on SSN, Date of Birth, Name, Gender, Last Updated Time

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, databricks

My environment is DataBricks and Apache Spark. I have a large medical patient dataset. I like to create a master patient table that keep track of patients that might change their name or gender over time. Date of birth and social security number do not change. In this large dataset, there are very similar records but different Patient IDs. Below is an example dataset.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PatientTable AS
SELECT '1'  PatientID, '100-10-fake' SSN, 'abby' FirstName, 'black' LastName, '2000-01-01' DateOfBirth, 'female' Gender, '2020-02-01' LastUpdateDateTime
UNION
SELECT '1a' PatientID, ''            SSN, 'abby' FirstName, 'black' LastName, '2000-01-01' DateOfBirth, 'female' Gender, '2020-01-01' LastUpdateDateTime
UNION
SELECT '2'  PatientID, '200-10-fake' SSN, 'ben'  FirstName, 'white' LastName, '2000-02-01' DateOfBirth, 'male'   Gender, '2020-01-01' LastUpdateDateTime
UNION
SELECT '3'  PatientID, '300-10-fake' SSN, 'ben'  FirstName, 'white' LastName, '2000-02-01' DateOfBirth, 'male'   Gender, '2020-02-01' LastUpdateDateTime
UNION
SELECT '3a' PatientID, ''            SSN, 'ben'  FirstName, 'white' LastName, '2000-02-01' DateOfBirth, 'male'   Gender, '2020-01-01' LastUpdateDateTime
UNION
SELECT '4'  PatientID, ''            SSN, 'chip' FirstName, 'smith' LastName, '2000-03-01' DateOfBirth, 'male'   Gender, '2020-01-01' LastUpdateDateTime;
```

[image]
Using SQL, I have created the Master Patient Table by using a Master Patient Reference Table first.

Master Patient Table:
[image]

Master Ref Patient Table
[image]

For the two Abby(s), I classify them as one patient because the second Abby is deemed as a duplicate because of the older LastUpdatedDateTime. The first two Ben(s) of Patient IDs of '2' and '3' are different because of different SSN. The third Ben (3a) is deemed a duplicate of Ben (3) because Ben (3) is the latest record. The end goal is to have Master Patient Table be updated if there are changes. If the Patient Table have new records that had Abby with a sex change to Male and a SSN for Chip, here is what the Master Patient Table should look like:

[image]

My SQL solution works well enough. However, I will start getting millions of patients from different medical institutions. Are there machine learning techniques for this? How should I implement ML into this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a clear sense of what variable differences constitute truly different entities: SSN and DOB. This seems like a great candidate for a rules based classification; if this, then this label; if that, then this label. This is not only a clear way to deliver immediately value, it’s also the first step in more sophisticated machine learning systems: create a benchmark classification model by which to evaluate further models.

Developing a machine learning model can be an enormous undertaking, subject to large initial investment and maintenance costs. And it’s not clear that this undertaking would pass a cost benefit analysis, given the clear relationships you’ve elucidated between inputs and outputs. Furthermore, any model would likely identify such a clear relationship you’re articulating and implicitly classify upon those variables. Before engaging in a highly labor and resource intensive ML operation, I’d urge you to try a rule based system, with maybe a hash lookup table of unique SSN + DOB combinations (or, judging from what I understand about SSNs, merely a hash table of SSNs).